# Conditional probability multiple iterations of probability (word problem)

Tags: probability, word-problem

I'm struggling to understand some word problems with my probability course that entails finding the probability of a specific event but then asking the probability of that event happening x times in a y timeframe.

Here's an example:

An individual without a car goes to work using one of two transportation methods: train or boat. He uses the boat 75% of the time, however the probability of arriving late is 15% while using the train the probability of arriving late is 5%.

Now I'm able to figure out the probability of arriving late and have arrived late what's the probability he took the boat but then there's another group of questions which I'm struggling with which is:

Determine the probability of arriving late 3 times in a week of work (5 days)
Determine the probability of arriving late at most 20 times in 100 days of work

So in this particular case, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Much appreciated

Comment: Once you know the probability, $p$,  of arriving late on a given day, you can just think of this as a binomial process with success rate $p$; the standard formulas then apply.

Comment: Note:  it isn't stated, but it is probably expected that you'll assume independence from day to day.  If you want some other assumption, you need to state what it is.

Comment: Thank you. Yes indeed these are independent events. The binomial process also applies to similar word problems involving continuous probability distribution functions like the normal distribution?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  A binomial process defines a distribution.  For large samples you can approximate that distribution with a normal if you want to.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: No, I meant for similar questions regarding the repetition of a probability using a continuous function. Example: spending at a shop is defined by a normal distribution and wanted to know the prob. that 3 out of next 10 customers will spend x. Knowing the prob. of spending x, I would use the binomial to determine the prob. of those 3 out of 10 spending x correct? Either way, thank you for helping

Comment: To get a binomial process, you just need independent trials with the same success probability.  Doesn't matter how you compute that success probability.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you